# chrome "--remote-debugging-port" not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I want to attach puppeteer to chrome, but that straight forward.

The problem is this doesn't work:

```
start chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

This runs and opens chrome as expected. The problem is not in debug mode. This should open a JSON on the browser:

```
127.0.0.1:9222/json/version
```

I have tried a lot already and it doesn't seem to work. Anyone knows why?

thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Its not a solution, but after a lot o trying, works perfectly in same way for firefox

```
start firefox --remote-debugging-port=9229
```